# Unit as parameter

Tags: scala

What is the following methods' difference?

```
def sum1() = 1+2

def sum2(a:Unit) = 1+2
```

I think they are semantically identical, is it right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `sum1`, you can call it with or without parentheses:

```
val x = sum1    // x: Int = 3
val y = sum1()  // y: Int = 3
```

But with `sum2` you are forced to provide parentheses.. I think that if you call `sum2()`, you are actually calling `sum2` with `()` as the argument `a`.

```
val x2 = sum2   // error
val y2 = sum2() // y2: Int = 3
```

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to require parens when the computation involves a side-effect, but don't require them when the computation is pure. I guess you could use parens this way in the same way that Lisp and Ruby use `!`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that passing unit as an argument to an expression lets you simulate lazy evaluation in a strict language. By "moving evaluation under a lambda" you ensure that the expression isn't eval'd until the `()` gets passed in. This can be useful for e.g. auto-memoizing data structures, which collapse from a function to a value the first time they're inspected.

Answer (score 2):

These methods are not identical. Once receives a parameter, the other does not. See here:

```
scala> sum1(println("Hi, there!"))
<console>:9: error: too many arguments for method sum1: ()Int
              sum1(println("Hi, there!"))
                  ^

scala> sum2(println("Hi, there!"))
Hi, there!
res1: Int = 3
```